# How to move around comments in any type of file?

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, cursor-movement

In `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/vim.vim`, some mappings are installed to move the cursor to the previous/next comment:

```
" Move around comments
nnoremap <silent><buffer> ]" :call search('^\(\s*".*\n\)\@<!\(\s*"\)', "W")<CR>
vnoremap <silent><buffer> ]" :<C-U>exe "normal! gv"<Bar>call search('^\(\s*".*\n\)\@<!\(\s*"\)', "W")<CR>
nnoremap <silent><buffer> [" :call search('\%(^\s*".*\n\)\%(^\s*"\)\@!', "bW")<CR>
vnoremap <silent><buffer> [" :<C-U>exe "normal! gv"<Bar>call search('\%(^\s*".*\n\)\%(^\s*"\)\@!', "bW")<CR>
```

They use the key sequences `["` and `]"`.

Are there similar mappings for other filetypes, or can we modify these mappings so that they work not only in Vim files but in other filetypes (shell, python, …)?

Answer (score 1):

There are similar mappings for other filetypes.

1. For c-style block comments there exist built-in, ft-independent mappings `[*`/`]*` (and as a synonym `[/`/`]/`)

```
/* 
This is the comment body.
Variation One.
*/
```

This type of block comment is used in many languages:

> ActionScript, AutoHotkey, C, C++, C#, D, Go, Java, JavaScript, kotlin, Objective-C, PHP, PL/I, Rust, Scala, SASS, SQL, Swift, Visual Prolog, CSS

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(syntax)#Block_comments)

2. Other mappings for certain filetypes in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/` exist:

   - `sql.vim` `["`, `]"` (same as `vim.vim`)
   - `eiffel.vim` `[-`, `]-`
   - `hamster.vim` `[#`, `]#` (overwrite built-in motions to jump to c-preprocessor `#ifdef` which are not used anyway in languages which do not have a c-preprocessor)

You can reuse them for languages with identical commentstrings by copying the code to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<language>.vim`.
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(syntax)#Inline_comments)

For example, consider the language `lua` which has the same commentstring as `eiffel`:

1. `:e $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/eiffel.vim`
2. `:45,91w ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/lua.vim`
3. remove unneeded code and change `g:no_eiffel_maps` to `g:no_lua_maps` and you should get something like

```viml
if !exists("g:no_plugin_maps") && !exists("g:no_lua_maps")
  function! s:DoMotion(pattern, count, flags) abort
    normal! m'
    for i in range(a:count)
      call search(a:pattern, a:flags)
    endfor
  endfunction

  let comment_block_start = '^\%(\s\+--.*\n\)\@<!\s\+--'
  let comment_block_end = '^\s\+--.*\n\%(\s\+--\)\@!'

  nnoremap <silent> <buffer> ]- :<C-U>call <SID>DoMotion(comment_block_start, 1, 'W')<CR>
  xnoremap <silent> <buffer> ]- :<C-U>exe "normal! gv"<Bar>call <SID>DoMotion(comment_block_start, 1, 'W')<CR>
  nnoremap <silent> <buffer> [- :<C-U>call <SID>DoMotion(comment_block_end, 1, 'Wb')<CR>
  xnoremap <silent> <buffer> [- :<C-U>exe "normal! gv"<Bar>call <SID>DoMotion(comment_block_end, 1, 'Wb')<CR>

  let b:undo_ftplugin = b:undo_ftplugin .
    \ "| silent! execute 'unmap <buffer> [-' | silent! execute 'unmap <buffer> ]-'"
endif
```